# ways to use a LAN-wide proxy

Tags: linux, proxy, openvpn

I have setup a pi-hole on home server and routed all my devices to use it via OpenVPN (all devices are constantly connected to the VPN and pi-hole is configures as the default DNS in the VPN settings).

Now, the next step I want to take is to configure a LAN-wide proxy that is either set via the pi-hole, the server or my router. I just don't want all my actions from every device to be backtrackable to my home ISP connection.

How do I achieve this? Will I have to install separate software to connect to proxies or can I configure an automatic connection to a proxy via my router, pi-hole or the server?

I'm quite inexperienced in using proxies so I'm very grateful for any hint.

Comment: You install the proxy-server onto your default gateway/router and remove the default-gateway from all other network devices and add the proxy instead, which is installed on your former default gateway/router.